# Reset MySQL default values programmatically

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-1.3

Is it possible to set default values for MySQL columns in CakePHP? I have access default value for user table as:

```
$fields = $this->User->schema(); 
$defaultValue = $fields['Amount']['default'];
```

Now I want to change this default value to any particular value provided by admin .. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try altering the schema:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.table
ADD CONSTRAINT def_mycolumn DEFAULT Amount FOR mycolumn
```

Comment: @ Tariq : I have use sql statement in model .. and alter table

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the MySQL table schema's `default` column attribute to store a value you plan to allow user(s) to modify.

You might consider some new `DefaultValues` table/model *(as one solution)* used to store the editable default for this `Amount` column and other similar columns. You could then conditionally check if a `User` instance's `Amount` has a null value when saved, setting it to the editable default retrieved from this new table. This provides you with the functionality you're looking for *(admin-editable defaults)* while being able to take advantage of Cake's built-in tables/models/forms to manage the storage/retrieval of these defaults.

Comment: @ Deefour : I know this solution but dun want to implement it as i've to create new table only for one field called as amount

Comment: The solution I provided above is simply to steer you in the right direction - away from allowing the management of your database schema in any way by your users. You could store this value in any number of places.